# Binding energy of an exciton

Tags: condensed-matter, charge, binding-energy, optical-materials

The binding energy of an exciton is usually modeled after the hydrogen atom and varies with charge $q$ as $q^4$. I don't understand why it is $q^4$ and not $q^2$ - If we assume an electron and hole, the interaction energy should vary as $q^2$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The energy levels of hydrogen are proportional to $e^4$, not $e^2$, so why would excitons be different? This is a prediction even of the simple Bohr model.

If the radius were independent of the charge, the energy would be proportional to $e^2$, but the radius *isn’t* independent of the charge. It’s proportional to $1/e^2$. For confirmation, see Wikipedia‘s article on the [Bohr radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr_radius).

Comment: Thanks @G.Smith. Somehow that flew over my head.